# Regex Field Match and Replace in a network-Python

Tags: python, regex, optimization, replace, dask

I have a large csv (+1000000 rows) that I need to do a regex search and replace function on. In short, I need to take two columns and find matches between them; and then use the matched rows to replace values in a third field with the matched rows. It basically matches certain assemblies in a network with their upstream component. Here is a small simplified example:

| OID | assembly | upstream | Field1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc123 |  | 1 |
| 2 | def456 | abc123 | 2 |
| 3 | ghi789 | jkl101 | 3 |
| 4 | jkl101 |  | 4 |

And here would be the expected result:

| OID | assembly | upstream | Field1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc123 |  | 1 |
| 2 | def456 | abc123 | 1 |
| 3 | ghi789 | jkl101 | 4 |
| 4 | jkl101 |  | 4 |

As you can see, any row with an upstream value that occurs in the "assembly" field gets a Field1 value equal to its upstream neighbor.

I have a perfectly serviceable, but very slow (write speed of about 15kb/s) code that I use currently using the regex module in python. My question is, what is a more efficient way to do this? Pandas is out of the question due to limited ram size, as is other data formats than csv. In the past I have tried dask, but never got it to work correctly, possibly because in my (very) restricted IT conditions - I don't have access to environment path variables in python.

Here is the code:

```
import csv
import re

#csv files
input_file = 'L:\\Dev_h\\Device Heirarchy\\fulljoin_device_flow2.csv'
output_file = 'L:\\Dev_h\\Device Heirarchy\\output2.csv'

# output fields
output_fields = ['gs_attached_assembly_guid', 'gs_upstream_aa_guid', 'Field1_num','Dev_no', 'gs_guid', 'gs_display_feature_guid', 'field2', 'gs_network_feature_name', 'gs_assembly_guid', 'gs_display_feature_name', 'Field1', 'gs_network_feature_guid', 'OID_']


with open(input_file, 'r', newline='') as in_csv, open(output_file, 'w', newline='') as out_csv:
    reader = csv.DictReader(in_csv)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(out_csv, fieldnames=output_fields)
    writer.writeheader()

    # Build Regex
    patterns = {row['gs_attached_assembly_guid']: row['Field1_num'] for row in reader}
    pattern = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, patterns.keys())))

    # restart loop
    in_csv.seek(0)
    next(reader) # Skip header row

    #for loop allowing pattern matching
    for row in reader:

        # Step 6: Define a function to search the 'gs_upstream_aa_guid' column using the regex pattern
        def search_and_replace(match):
            matched_guids = match.group().split(',')
            replacement_values = []
            for matched_guid in matched_guids:
                if matched_guid in patterns and patterns[matched_guid] != '':
                    replacement_values.append(patterns[matched_guid])
                else:
                    # Return an empty string instead of the gs_attached_assembly_guid
                    replacement_values.append('')

            return ','.join(replacement_values)

        # check for matches in 'gs_upstream_aa_guid' value
        match = pattern.search(row['gs_upstream_aa_guid'])

        #If there is a match, replace the 'Field1_num' value with the matched value
        if match:
            row['Field1'] = search_and_replace(match)
        #Otherwise skip
        else:
            pass

        #Write the updated row out to the output CSV
        writer.writerow(row)

print("End")
```

So the question is, how to speed this process up?

Comment: Why even use regex for this? Do 2 passes instead: 1st build a dictionary/map from `assembly` value to `OID` value. Then read the CSV again and use the dictionary/map to update the `Field1` value.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride I am self taught on python within the last two months or so, didn't know it was an option. Can you elucidate me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

As you can't use pandas due to memory limitations, the simplest approach is to build a replacements dictionary on the first pass of reading the csv, then use that to replace `Field1` values on the second pass. Using your code as a starting point, modified for the sample data in the question:

```py
output_fields = ['OID', 'assembly', 'upstream', 'Field1']

with open(input_file, 'r', newline='') as in_csv, open(output_file, 'w', newline='') as out_csv:
    reader = csv.DictReader(in_csv)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(out_csv, fieldnames=output_fields)
    writer.writeheader()
    
    # Build replacements dict
    reps = { row['assembly'] : row['Field1'] for row in reader }
    
    # restart loop
    in_csv.seek(0)
    next(reader) # Skip header row
    
    for row in reader:
        # update if required
        # use dict.get to allow keeping the original value when no replacement
        row['Field1'] = reps.get(row['upstream'], row['Field1'])
        # Write the updated row out to the output CSV
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Output for your sample data:

```
OID,assembly,upstream,Field1
1,abc123,,1
2,def456,abc123,1
3,ghi789,jkl101,4
4,jkl101,,4
```

**Original answer**

You could just use pandas, using a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to match the `upstream` values with the `assembly` values and fetch the appropriate `Field1` values:

```
df = pd.read_csv(input_file)
df['Field1'] = (df
    .merge(df, left_on='upstream', right_on='assembly', how='left')['Field1_y']
    .fillna(df['Field1'])
     # necessary because the presence of NaN after the merge changes type to float
    .astype(int)
)
df.to_csv(output_file, index=False)
```

Comment: Unfortunately pandas only works in chunks because of the large size, it is maxing out ram. I could do it in chunks, but I would have to build a dictionary, because technically a match could be found in any row of the dataset.

Comment: @JacksonDunn sorry about the slow reply, been on holiday. 1M rows shouldn't be an issue for pandas, how much RAM do you have in the system? Do you run out of RAM during the read, or during the merge?

Comment: I have 8gb, but huge rows. The file is well over 1.2gb, and my computer is a toaster :(

Comment: @JacksonDunn can you successfully read the file into pandas?

Comment: No it fails on the read.

Comment: @JacksonDunn Ah well pandas is definitely not the solution then :-P Please see my edit based on your original code. This takes the same approach as Aurelien's answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building a *large* regex, you can simply remove and replace

```
match = pattern.search(row['gs_upstream_aa_guid'])
```

By

```
match = row['gs_upstream_aa_guid'] in patterns
```

[Regexes can be fast](https://swtch.com/%7Ersc/regexp/regexp1.html), but never as fast as checking the existence of a value in a dictionary, because the [complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity) is *O(1)*.

*O(1)* means that checking the existence of a value in a dictionary containing 1 value is as fast as checking the existence of a value in a dictionary containing 1,000,000 values.

Comment: This is a good idea, but it's trowing me an error: Bool object has no attribute group. I'll try to debug and see if it works, thanks!